# Spring Boot Security Custom Member & Roles

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I've go two problems, my entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Member {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@Email
@NotNull
private String email;

private String password;

private boolean enabled;

@Transient
private String passwordConfirm;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "member_role",
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "member_id"),
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public boolean getEnabled() {
  return enabled;
}
}

@Entity
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Getter
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Getter
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private Set<Member> members;
}
```

I've managed to create full user CRUD with assigning to roles.
Now I need to override this method in order to get My roles and then secure my url's

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

 //    List<Role> roles = roleRepository.findMemberRoles(this.member.getId());
 //    for(Role role : roles){
 //      authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
 //    }
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")); // just for test
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("test"));  // just for test

    return authorities;

}
```

problems:
1. how to get roles assigned to user
2. if point 1 then is simple to change getAuthorities() method.

EDIT:

```
 public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

 @Autowired
 RoleRepository roleRepository;

 @Autowired
 MemberRepository memberRepository;

private Member member;

public Member getMember() {
    return member;
}

public void setMember(Member member) {
    this.member = member;
}

public UserDetailsImpl(Member member) {
    this.member = member;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

Set<Role> roles = member.getRoles(); // not
for(Role r : roles) { // working
  authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.getName())); // at all :)
}
    //authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")); // hardcoded this works
    //authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("test"));

    return authorities;

}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return member.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return member.getEmail();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
return member.getEnabled();
}
}
```

Comment: And you happily fail to explain where you are implementing this `getAuthorities()`  method.

Comment: I'm implementig it in UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails class

Comment: Why doesn't your `Member` simply implements `UserDetails` or if you don't want that, simply configure the correct queries for Spring Security to use the default user and authorities based on your database model.

Comment: I simply need to get roles in getAuthorities() method and I don't know how, e.g. @Query in RoleRepository I've tried and something not working, Transient in Entity?

Comment: Again why are you creating a custom object, your member should be implementing `UserDetails` instead. Or ditch the custom object and correctly configure the queries that Spring Security uses. You either are creating the wrong object or you don't need the object.

Comment: M. Deinum please look above, I've edited my post and paste whole UserDetailsImpl class

Comment: Your approach is wrong... Also if you have the `Member` just get the roles. However I strongly suggest (as the `Member` is a JPA object) to not store it in the `UserDetailsImpl` just copy the parameters needed. But as mentioned I would argue you would need this, just pass the correct queries OR let the `Member` implements the correct interface.